# How to properly pass argument in loop to multiple event handlers?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I add event handlers to multiple hrefs on my website with JS like this:

```
function addButtonListener(){
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("selLink");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  {
      button.addEventListener('click',function() { addTosel(i); },true);
    }
  }
}
```

But  unfortunately to addTosel is passed the last i not the i from the loop. How to pass i accordingly to the object being processed in this moment?

Comment: sounds like you're needing a 'bind' function to get aroudn the async code you've written. will post a quick answer soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a closure:

```
function addButtonListener(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("selLink");

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        button.addEventListener('click', function(index) { 
            return function () {
                addTosel(index);
            };
        }(i), true);
    }
}
```

This way the scope of the handler is bound to the proper context of `i`.

See this [article](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/02/17/javascript-closures-explained/) for more information on this subject.

Comment: I think you messed up the place when to call the function and where to pass the argument.

Comment: @pimvdb yeah, it's supposed to be the outer anonymous, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `i` variable to the function when its declared. like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  button.addEventListener('click',(function() { addTosel(this); }).bind(i) ,true);
}
```

Note: I just wrote the code from memory so it may not be perfect, but it is the sulution you're needing, for reference as to the proper way, ie with cross browser shims etc look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: This would make the index a `Number` object. To keep it a primitive you'd need `"use strict";`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to take the `.bind` approach, do it like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   button.addEventListener('click', addTosel.bind(null, i), true);
}
```

This makes a new function with `null` bound as the `this` value since your function doesn't seem to need it, and the current `i` bound as the first argument.

Or make your own binder function

```
var _slice = Array.prototype.slice;
function _binder(func, ctx /*, arg1, argn */) {
    var bound_args = _slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function() {
        return func.apply(ctx, bound_args.concat(_slice.call(arguments)));
    }
}
```

And then do this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   button.addEventListener('click', _binder(addTosel, null, i), true);
}
```